# How to show $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(2n+1)!!}{2^nn!(2n-1)}=0$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

I have a question: show 
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(2n+1)!!}{2^nn!(2n-1)}=0. $$
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you know [the relation of the double factorial to the factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial#Relation_to_the_factorial) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$(2n+1)!! = \dfrac{(2n+2)!}{2^{n+1}(n+1)!}$$
Hence, we have
$$\dfrac{(2n+1)!!}{2^n n! (2n-1)} = \dfrac{(2n+2)!}{2^{2n+1}(n+1)!n!(2n-1)} = \underbrace{\dfrac{\dbinom{2n+2}{n+1}}{2^{2n+2}}}_{\downarrow 0} \overbrace{\dfrac{2n+2}{2n-1}}^{\downarrow 1} \to 0$$

Comment: It is a nice solution. Thanks.

Comment: Why is ${2n+2\choose n+1}\ll4^n$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen It is because $2^{2n+2}=\sum_{k=0}^{2n+2}\binom{2n+2}{k}$.

Answer (score 3):

Define

$$a_n:=\frac{(2n+1)!!}{2^nn!(2n-1)}\implies \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(2n+3)!!}{2^{n+1}(n+1)!(2n+1)}\frac{2^nn!(2n-1)}{(2n+1)!!}=$$

$$=\frac12\frac{2n-1}{(2n+1)^2}\frac1{n+1}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$$

Thus, by the quotient test (D'Alembert's Test) for positive (infinite) series , we have that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\;\;\text{converges}\;\implies\;a_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$$

Comment: It is very nice. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

$$ (2n+1)!!=\prod_{1\le k\le 2n+1\atop k\text{ odd}}k$$
and 
$$2^nn!=\prod_{1\le k\le 2n\atop k\text{ even}}k$$
so
$$ \frac{(2n+1)!!}{2^nn!(2n-1)}=\frac{2n+1}{2n-1}\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2k-1}{2k}=\frac{2n+1}{2n-1}\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1-\frac1{2k}\right)$$

Since $\frac{2n+1}{2n-1}\to 1$, we need to show that the product $\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.
We show that the $\ln$ of the product diverges $\to-\infty$.
Indeed, for $\epsilon>0$ we have $\ln(1-\epsilon)<-\epsilon$, hence 
$$\ln \prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1-\frac1{2k}\right)\le -\frac12\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1k$$
and the result follows by divergence of the harmonic series.